# Set laravel valet to use a driver for Jigsaw

Tags: laravel, java-platform-module-system, laravel-valet

I want to use Jigsaw to create a static site. I am using laravel valet for my other projects

There is a Valet Driver for Jigsaw.

https://github.com/laravel/valet/blob/master/cli/drivers/JigsawValetDriver.php

But I can't see how to tell Valet to use this for my installation. I only want it to be used for this one project.

at the moment if I go to my site url I get a 404.

so how can I tell valet to use this driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok so it turns out i was being thick, I don't need to do anything as the driver just works.

I had not run the build command for jigsaw